# how to prove that $1^x+2^x+3^x+4^x+\cdots+N^x$ will never sum to a prime number except $1^x+2^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, stirling-numbers, bernoulli-numbers

I am a a web developer programming in PhP which is limited to large calculations, but running a quick script shows that $1^x+2^x+3^x+4^x+\cdots+N^x$ can never sum to a prime number unless in the case of $1^x+2^x$, such as in the cases of $x=1$ and $x=2$ where $1^1+2^1=3$ and $1^2+2^2=5$.

As a self learner, I am currently refreshing my learning in Algebra 2 (before moving on), and sometimes my mind wonders into questions that I just can't find the answers to (mostly because I am not familiar with the concerned topics). I tried finding an answer but if this is a duplicate with a relevant answer, please close and refer me to it.

How to prove (if possible) that $1^x+2^x+3^x+4^x+\cdots+N^x$ will never be the sum of a prime number, unless in the case of $1^x+2^x$, such as in the cases of $x=1$ and $x=2$ where $1^1+2^1=3$ and $1^2+2^2=5$?

Edit: $x$ and $N$ are positive integers

I appreciate any answers even if it is just a hint or a reference.

Comment: There are other cases, for example, $\;1^4+2^4=17\;,\;1^8+2^8=257\;.$

Comment: Do you intend that $x$ is a (positive) integer?

Comment: There are formulas for the sum of the first $n$ powers of natural numbers (at least for the first few $n$). By analyzing these formulas, one may perhaps argue using divisibility arguments that the sums are indeed composite for large $N$.

Comment: @Eric Towers I have reedited the question

Comment: @Angelo Thank you for the confirmation. I have reedited the question per your comment

Comment: This is interesting. Letting 
$$S(n,r)=\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$$
I have found no prime values other than the cases mentioned all the way up to $r=50,n=1000$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: I conjecture that it is always possible to factor $S_r(n)$ with integer coefficients. I am not sure if I have the mathematical chops to prove this however.

Comment: If x is odd, $N+1$ divides twice the number - you can pair the first and last terms, etc.  Not sure how to do the even case. One useful fact is that if p divided $N+1$ and $p-1$ doesn’t divide $X$, then you can show $p$ divides the sum.

Comment: @K.defaoite I have a feeling that this is also the case with $(1^x)+(1^x+2^x)+ (1^x+2^x+3^x)+ (1^x+2^x+3^x+4^x)...$ However my php script gets overloaded quickly and keeps collapsing. (I might be wrong though

Comment: I think you missed some clause.For every $X$ there should be some minimum $N$ from which it is always composite. For $X=1,n_{min}=2$, For $X=2,n_{min}=3$, For $X=3,n_{min}=2$, For $X=4,n_{min}=3$.For $X=1440$ @resuns have found a small N=5 for which it beaks, for $X=1440$ min composite $N$ must be higher.To understand intuitively,if you remember Faulhaber's formulas they are expressed as factors with a constant in denominator.So product of the factors except the largest one has to be greater than the denominator for it to be always composite(assuming that largest factor turns out to be prime)

Comment: @IsaacBrenig More interesting question would be to find a generalised identity/approximation for that minimum value of $N$ for a given $X$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a counter-example

$$A=\sum_{n=1}^5 n^{1440}$$

[image]

It took about 30 minutes to run the primality test, a faster check is with

```
         ispseudoprime(sum(n=1,5,n^1440))
```

that you can try there https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html

My script to find more candidates ($A$ is the smallest one)

```
      lambda(n)=znstar(n)[2][1];  # carmichael function
      f(a,b) =sum(j=1,a,j^b);
      maxlog=100000;
      for (n=3,300,{ b=lambda(n*(n+1)); l = b*log(n); for (k=1,floor( maxlog/l), if(ispseudoprime(f(n,k*b)), print("prime ",n," ",k*b),print(n," ",k*b)))})
```

Comment: Well, just one counterexample is worth more than ten-thousand promising proof attempts. Very nice.

Comment: WOW! I must admit I was quite convinced this conjecture was true. This is high up on my list of favorite counterexamples ever!

Comment: You could have saved yourself a lot of computation and just checked whether or not the number was prime on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=IsPrime%5B1%2B2%5E%281440%29%2B3%5E%281440%29%2B4%5E%281440%29%2B5%5E%281440%29%5D) ;)

Comment: @K.defaoite Wolfram alpha is obviously doing a pseudoprime test. The integer is very large.

Comment: @K.defaoite Wolfram's documentation on this point is poor. Wolfram Alpha is using Mathematica's `PrimeQ` function, which is a probable primality test despite not saying so anywhere in its manual page. You need to use `ProvablePrimeQ` to make certain. I let it grind away for a couple hours in this case since I was curious about how well Pari does against it, and the Mathematica version didn't finish--so, point to Pari. To be fair to Wolfram, it would be a safe bet that the output of `PrimeQ` and `ProvablePrimeQ` will never differ on input any human will ever use over the history of our species.

Comment: parfor wasn't able to speed this up ? instead of floor you could have used \  for Euclidean division,

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The costly step is by far ispseudoprime.

Comment: okay so make the second for :... parfor(k=1,maxlog\l, ispseudoprime(f(n,k*b)),c,if(c,print("prime ",n," c,"k*b),print(n," ","k,*b)))})

Answer (score 9):

Faulhaber's formula is frankly not good. It does not deserve to be as popular as it is. A better formula is

$$1^x + 2^x + \cdots + N^x = \sum_{k=1}^x k! \left\{ {x \atop k}\right\} \binom{N+1}{k+1} \qquad (\text{for }x \geq 1).$$

Here $\left\{ {x \atop k}\right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), which is a non-negative integer with simple combinatorial meaning much like the binomial coefficients $\binom{N+1}{k+1}$. This formula is cancellation-free and doesn't involve anything "mysterious" like the Bernoulli numbers.

From this formula, we've got $k!$ in each term, so it's pretty plausible that we'll "usually" get composites. Ok, but when do we actually get a composite?

First off, every term with $k \geq 2$ is divisible by $2$. The $k=1$ term is just $\binom{N+1}{2} = (N+1)N/2$. This will be even when $N=4m$ or $N=4m+3$. So, we can suppose $N=4m+1$ or $N=4m+2$.

Every term with $k \geq 3$ is divisible by $3$. When are the other two terms also divisible by $3$? When
$$\left\{{x \atop 1}\right\} \binom{N+1}{2} + \left\{{x \atop 2}\right\} \binom{N+1}{3} = \frac{(N+1)N}{2} + (2^{x-1} - 1) \frac{(N+1)N(N-1)}{6}$$
is divisible by $3$. This occurs for instance when $3 \mid \frac{(N+1)N}{2}$ and $3 \mid 2^{x-1} - 1$, so when $N=3m$ or $N=3m+2$ and $x$ is odd.

Now reuns has found a counterexample with 5 terms. That fits with this heuristic. A lot of modular congruence conditions have to work out simultaneously to get counterexamples.

Comment: I like this formula a lot. Where did you find it?

Comment: As I am learning the heuristic, just to make sure: Does it mean that there is no direct proof?

Comment: Your analysis of each case (divisibility by $2$, divisibility by $3$) is wrong.  The binomial is $\binom{N+1}{k+1}$, but you use $\binom{N+1}{k}$.

Comment: @JacobManaker Thanks, I've fixed it up.

Comment: @IsaacBrenig reuns has found a counterexample to your claim, so there is indeed no proof. This heuristic begins to explain why counterexamples are rare, at least. There's going to be a rat's nest of modular congruence conditions that will all have to work out *just right* for the result to happen to be prime.

Comment: @K.defaoite That formula is well-known in combinatorics. It's for instance formula (28) at [MathWorld's Stirling number of the second kind article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html). It also follows very quickly from the definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind (e.g. equation (11)) and the hockey stick identity.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson Your answer explains why it is happening,  but I guess I should of never assumed that there wasn’t the possibility for a counter example. By setting me correct I had to accept the other answer. These rarities are just fascinating. I would of been ready to make a bet that there were no counter examples.

Comment: Programmers neither like Faulhaber(and Bernoulli) nor Sirling . They prefer EGF https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/60756

Comment: @sibillalazzerini I don't think I'd agree with the claim that programmers prefer EGF's, though I do. They're a repackaging of the Faulhaber formula.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Unlike humanities In maths no one needs to agree or disagree with another as there are always numerical ways to measure, in these kinds of algorithms time complexity and memory complexity speaks for itself.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini Well you were the one who introduced non-mathematical claims in the first place. You'll have to be clearer about exactly which situation the EGF approach is better in. The only source of speed-up over Faulhaber would be if you do FFT multiplication, though these are power series so it's a little unusual. When I said the Stirling formula is "better", I had in mind that the arithmetic can be done over integers with no substraction. I did not intend to make asymptotic claims (which I do not really care about here).

Comment: I thought you were the one who started on popularity based on your likeliness in which I don't see any mathematical-ness. Anyways nevermind, Yes exactly I believe speedup due tp FFT was the big difference on time side and and memory to hardcode/load a million+ of Bernoulli numbers were the one of the reason to reject it. I had same issue with huge memory requirement with Stirling.  The next time around I work with those those I would try to benchmark and link to this discussion. And I am talking about FFT at a scale where I get negligible error in integer domain, so no real approximation.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini This discussion of popularity is unproductive, so let's skip it. I'd be curious to see an application of these formulas where the formulas themselves are the limiting factor. I do not know how you were computing Stirlings; perhaps it was an inefficient method? I do not know what you mean about "negligible error in integer domain". If you just want an asymptotic, $N^{x+1}/(x+1)$ is pretty close.

Comment: But negligible error I meant I only worked with 32bit integers and NTT in 32bit integers don't have any precision error which was your worry. As long as I have zero error why should I care if I reached there by asymptotic or deterministic path ? By zero I really mean perfectly zero when converted to integers. By the way since you are a researcher in q-Stirlings numbers can you share efficient implementation/library for it.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini This is getting fairly far afield from the original question, but my first thought for computing the Stirlings of the second kind, $S(x, k)$, for a fixed $x$ and all $0 \leq k \leq x$ is to use the generating function identity $\sum_{k=0}^x S(x, k) t^{\underline{k}} = t^x$. Here $t^{\underline{k}}$ is a falling factorial. SageMath's built-in `stirling_number2` method uses Maxima or GAP's implementations; Maxima seems faster in a little testing. You're not going to get to $x$ in the "millions". Already for $x=2000$ the largest coefficient has 4348 digits, well past 32-bit.

Comment: Yes these are far from the original question.Lets clean up last few comments. I have been meaning to learn more about stirling2 for a while especially q-stirling2. Stumbling across a researcher in it,I forgot about the thread's relevance and started discussion.Let me know if there is any math.stachexchange/mathoverflow thread I should follow.Being from programming, I typically start learning from some code implementation or math.exchange post and then look into publication. But I must say I am very disappointed with number theory researchers as they rarely publish code alongside their paper.

Answer (score 1):

This is also only a partial solution that may provide more insight.

We can split into two cases, $x$ even and odd.

If $x$ is odd, then note that $i^x \equiv -(n-i)^x \mod n$. Then, consider $1^x+ 2^x...+n^x$ If $n$ is odd, we can pair up $1$ and $n-1$, etc. Each pair’s sum is divisible by $n$, $n^n$ is divisible by $n$ and the total is greater than $n$ and divisible by it and so composite. If $n$ is even, we can pair up 1 and $n$, etc and get that the sum is divisible by $n+1$ and divisible by it and is greater than it when either n or x are greater than 2.

If $x$ is even, then it’s trickier. By considering Vieta’s formula, it’s possible to show that $p| 1^x +2^x ... + (p-1)^x$ whenever $p-1$ does not divide $x$. This means that if $p$ divides $N$ and $p-1$ doesn’t divide $x$ then you can break up the sum into groups of size $p$ each divisible by $p$. Similarly if $p$ divides $N+1$, you can do the same thing by adding the $N+1$ term which is divisible by $p$. Similarly, you can double the sum and get terms from $1$ to $2N$ module $2N+1$.  Thus, if $p$ doesn’t divide the sum and is a divisor of either $x$, $x+1$, or $2x+1$, then $p-1$ divides $N$.

Additionally, if $p^2$ divides $x$,$x+1$, or $2x+1$, then since each of the aforementioned groupings is the same module $p$ and their are now a multiple of $p$ of them, $p$ would divide the sum. This, in order for $p$ to not divide the sum, $x$, $x+1$, and $2x+1$ must not be divisible by its square.

In particular, this means for a given $n$, all of the primes of $x$, $x+1$, $2x+1$ are of the finite set of those for which $p-1$ divides $N$ and they are squarefree, so there are only a finite number of cases to check. Also, note that $x$,$x+1$, and $2x+1$ are relatively prime, so their primes are disjoint.

One other interesting fact is that if $p-1$ divides $n$, then everything is 0 or 1 mod p, so p divides the sum iff p divides $x - \lfloor x/p \rfloor$

It’s possible to use these facts to work through the small cases and quickly narrow things down to fairly large numbers.

In particular, if x is 2, the primes 2,3,5 divide $x$,$x+1$,$2x+1$, so 1,2,4 divides $N$, so $N$ is a multiple of 4. In fact, all the prime examples are the Fermat primes.

$x$ can’t be 3 since $x+1=4$ is not squarefree.

$x$ can’t be 4 since it’s squarefree.

If $x$ is 5, then to eliminate 5,2*3,11, we need $\operatorname{lcm}(5-1,2-1,3-1,11-1)=20$ to divide N. The smallest such example $1^{20}+2^{20}+3^{20}+4^{20}+5^{20}$ is divisible by 137. The fact that there can be a factor significantly larger than both $x$ and $n$ suggests that this kind of brute force approach with small factors is unlikely to completely solve the problem.

If $x$ is 6, then $2x+1$ is 13, so 12 divides N.  Therefore $4=5-1$ divides N and $6=5+\lfloor 6/5 \rfloor$, so 5 will divide the sum of powers.

We can continue in the vein and eliminate many small numbers. In particular, I find that if $x$ is 10, then N must be a multiple of 60. If x is 21, then $N$ is a multiple of 210. If $x$ is 29, N is a multiple of $812=4*7*29$. Etc.

I’m not sure how to proceed from here. Even the simplest exceptional case here $1^{20}+2^{20}+3^{20}+4^{20}+5^{20}$ seems difficult to figure out that it’s composite and a multiple of 137 without brute force.